# How to assign value returned by service's $http.get() to a variable in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-http

I have created the separate service for fetching data from server, but I want to assign the data that this service returns to variable in the controllers. in this case data is a simple JSON file.

Here is my service

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('TextService', ['$http', function CompanyService($http) {
      var service = {};
      $http.get('text.json').
            then(function (response) {
                service.text = response.data.text;
                console.log(response.data.text);
            }, function (response) {
                alert(response);
            });


      return service;
  }]);
```

and here is my controller

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', 'TextService', function($scope, TextService){

    $scope.text = TextService.text;


}]);
```

then I try to display $scope.text, but it does not work. (I have controller assigned in html)

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>{{text}}</h1>
</div>
```

I guess I will need to use some helper function since, TextService is asynchronous. I would love to understand how to make it work and why it is not working now. and is it a good structure to wrap $http call in service?

Comment: the `text` property actually has the data stored in it. You should use `TextService.text` instead of just `TextService`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service must provide methods to get text :

```
angular.module('app')
.service('TextService', ['$http', '$q', function CompanyService($http, $q) {
    var text;
    var service = {
      getText: function() {
          var defered = $q.defer();
          if(text == undefined) {
            $http.get('text.json').then(function success(data) {
              text = data.text;
              deferred.resolve(data.text); 
            },
             function error(err) { defered.reject(err) });
           }
           else {
             defered.resolve(text);
           }
           return defered.promise;
      }
  };
  return service;
}]);
```

And your controller call the service :

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', 'TextService', function($scope,    TextService){
 TextService.getText().then(function(text) { $scope.text = text } );
}]);
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but is it possible for service to return just data from server? since now every time I would need this data in different controller, I have to execute HTTP request, while with service returning data it would happen only once.

Comment: I update my sample. You can store the value the first time you call your server and use a promise to manage if you call server or if you get stored value.

Comment: Or you can do your http request outside the service object

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this in your **HTML**:

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>{{text.text}}</h1>
</div>
```

**Or** if you prefer in your **Controller**:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', 'TextService', function($scope, TextService){
    $scope.text = TextService.text;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TextService.text` instead of just `TextService` in the controller.`TextService` assigns the response to a `text` property which you need to access-

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.service('TextService',  function CompanyService() {
      var service = {};
      service.text = "hello world";
      return service;
});
app.controller("MyController", ['TextService', function(TextService){
    this.text = TextService.text;
}]);
```

**HTML** -

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <p>{{ myCtrl.text }}</p>
</div>
```